# Why does postgres tell me column 'airline' doesn't exist when I know it does?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying this simple modification on a query from a PostgreSQL course. The original works fine and is as follows:

```
SELECT  fl_date
        ,mkt_carrier AS airline
        ,mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
        ,origin
        ,dest
  FROM  performance
 WHERE  dest = 'ORD'
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDFJY.jpg)

Now instead of `destination`, I'm asking to only show a certain `airline`:

```
SELECT  fl_date
        ,mkt_carrier AS airline
        ,mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
        ,origin
        ,dest
  FROM  performance
 WHERE  airline = 'UA'
```

..but instead of giving a result it spits back the following:

```
ERROR:  column "airline" does not exist
LINE 7:  WHERE  airline = 'UA'
                ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 145
```

Clearly this column does exist; I see it in the initial result set. What am I missing?

Comment: You can not use alias in condition when you are using PostgreSQL. You need to use real references.

Comment: The reason the column does not exist is that the `where` clause is processed **before** the specific select columns and their alias names are determined. So from Postgres viewpoint the column *airline* does not exist at the point of processing the where clause.  So Clearly this column does not exist;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't use column alias name in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`. You have to use real reference name in `WHERE`

```sql
SELECT  fl_date
        ,mkt_carrier AS airline
        ,mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
        ,origin
        ,dest
  FROM  performance
 WHERE  mkt_carrier = 'UA'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use where, group by, ... clause alias. Use real column names

```sql
SELECT  fl_date
        ,mkt_carrier AS airline
        ,mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
        ,origin
        ,dest
  FROM  performance
 WHERE  mkt_carrier = 'UA'
```